# Exporting CSV from Rails postgres database - Adding Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, activerecord, associations

I am trying to export information about users of my Rails app (that's hosted by Heroku).  I followed this tutorial to export a CSV file:

https://coderwall.com/p/jwtxjg

This involved the following:

1. Connecting to post-gres database:

   *psql "dbname=foo host=bar.compute-1.amazonaws.com user=abc password=123 port=5432 sslmode=require"*
2. Running a query:

   *\copy (SELECT id, sign_in_count, last_sign_in_at, created_at FROM users) TO dump.csv CSV DELIMITER ','*

This exported the CSV file to my current directory.

However, I'd also like to include an associated model in the query - for example, in my app, users created projects, and I'd like to export the number of projects each user has created.

How can I update my query to do this?

Comment: Are the user created projects store in your database?

Comment: yes, projects are stored on the same database

Answer (score 0):

You'd try adding a count of the registries that matches the given user_id (Assuming there's a field called user_id). Something like this:

> \copy (SELECT u.id, u.sign_in_count, u.last_sign_in_at, u.created_at,
>   count(p.project) 
>           FROM users u, projects p
>           WHERE p.user_id = u.id
>           GROUP BY u.id, u.sign_in_count, u.last_sign_in_at u.created_at) TO dump.csv CSV DELIMITER ','

Assuming there'd only be 1 registry per user at the Users table, this should work.

Comment: thanks for your help.  a project can have many users, so I don't have a single column (user_id) to reference the users of a particular project.  I tried to update the query as follows:
\copy (SELECT u.id, u.sign_in_count, u.last_sign_in_at, u.created_at, count(p.project) FROM users u, projects p WHERE p.users.pluck(:id).include? u.id GROUP BY u.id, u.sign_in_count, u.last_sign_in_at, u.created_at) TO dump.csv CSV DELIMITER ','
But I get the error: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: ... ) FROM users u, projects p WHERE p.users.pluck ( :id ) .inc... 
The error refers to :id

Comment: How you make the relation between User and Project? Which column is it based on?

Comment: a user has and belongs to many projects, and a project has and belongs to many users